# Apache + Dir Alias + htaccess y virtualhost _default_:443 ( localhost vs IP Publica)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

No puedo entrar a un directoria, que en **Apache 2.4** esta configurado como alias, para ese **vhost**, ya que al tener un **htaccess**, que redirecciona todo a un archivos index.php, no toma la prioridad del alias y se pasa la ruta al index.php. en lugar de tomar como prioridad el alias que la ruta tendría que ser ejemplo.

**URL Archivos alias**

```
192.168.1.1:111/facturtas/dsdsdsdsdsdsds.pdf
192.168.1.1:111/facturtas/*.pdf
```

**Mi htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Y lo raro es que si entro como https://localhost/facturas/dsdsdsdsdsdsds.pdf no hay problema.

Pero si entro con una IP publica ejemplo **https://192.168.1.1:111/facturas/dsdsdsdsdsdsds.pdf** se lo pasa al index.php en lugar de bajar el pdf como lo hace con localhost.

Esto esta por **IP publica, puerto 111 <=> NAT <=> ip privada puerto 443** todo funciona perfecto, pero el problema esta con la entrega de los PDF que estan en un alias cuando es llamado desde el internet, no entra los PDF, cae en el index.php, es como si de internet no existe el alias, pero si en **localhost**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/www/api/www/webroot"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@localhost
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

Alias "/facturas" "//VBOXSVR/Fac"
<Directory "//VBOXSVR/Fac">

    LimitRequestBody 512000

    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI -SymLinksifOwnerMatch -MultiViews
    #Options none

    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

.....
.....

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion al problema estaba en la configuracion de apache del vhost

Quite de mi `<VirtualHost _default_:443> ... </virtualhost>` las reglas de alias y directorio y las agregue afuera del `<VirtualHost>` y funciono todo correctamente con localhost y las ip publica a internet.

```
Alias "/facturas" "//VBOXSVR/Fac"
<Directory "//VBOXSVR/Fac">
        LimitRequestBody 512000
        Options -FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI -SymLinksifOwnerMatch -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   #   General setup for the virtual host
   DocumentRoot "C:/www/api/www/webroot"
   ServerName localhost:443
   ServerAdmin admin@localhost
   ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
   TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
   .....
   .....
</VirtualHost>
```

Espero que le sea útil a otros mi problema.